# Want to use multiple foreach for showing the result in table

Tags: php, foreach

I want to send the content of message to email in table format and for that i have use 3 `foreach` statement but problem is that it show the table result like following image
[image of table generated](http://postimg.org/image/rhr2aso2j/) 
the code of php are given

```html
$msg.='<hr color="#000000" style="height:2px;" />'        ;
$msg.='<table width="400" align="center" border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>';
$msg.='<tr class="titles">';
$msg.='<td style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;" >Menu Name</td>';
$msg.='<td style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;">Quantity</td>';
$msg.='<td style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;">Price</td>';
$a=$_POST['prdct'];
$b=$_POST['quantity'];
$c=$_POST['price'];
        foreach ($a as $k=>$qt)
{

$msg.='</tr><tr><td style="padding-left:3px;">'. $qt.'</td>';}
  foreach($b as $x=>$quantity) {
$msg.='<td style="padding-left:3px;">'.$quantity.'</td>';
  }
foreach($c as $y=>$price) {
$msg.='<td style="padding-left:3px;">'.$price.'</td></tr>';
}
```

is there any solution for using single `foreach` instead of multiple `foreach`

Comment: and how do you think such a for loop will ever work, that would be against the very nature of the loop, start with a variable until an end condition, inc/dec the variable and loop stops at the end condition, having 2 variables will just flout the basic understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this

```
$msg.='<hr color="#000000" style="height:2px;" />'        ;
$msg.='<table width="400" align="center" border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>';
$msg.='<tr class="titles">';
$msg.='<td style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;" >Menu Name</td>';
$msg.='<td style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;">Quantity</td>';
$msg.='<td style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;">Price</td>';
$msg.='</tr>';

$a=$_POST['prdct'];
$b=$_POST['quantity'];
$c=$_POST['price'];

 foreach ($a as $k=>$qt)
{
$msg.='<tr>';
$msg.='<td style="padding-left:3px;">'. $qt.'</td>';
$msg.='<td style="padding-left:3px;">'.$b[$k].'</td>';
$msg.='<td style="padding-left:3px;">'.$c[$k].'</td>';
$msg.='</tr>';
}
$msg.='</table ';
```

Comment: Yes sir if any similar suggestion